# Sort UITableView with double

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying create a UITableView that is sorted by the size of the latitude value found in the database. Although my UITable Cells display all the names of the shops and the console prints the latitude, I still cannot figure out how to sort the cells by their own latitude value. Here is my current code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nearbyTableView: UITableView!
var myList: [String] = []
var handle:DatabaseHandle?
var ref:DatabaseReference?


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellName
    return cell

}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    var (cellName) = myList[indexPath.row]

     let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home2") as! ShopViewController
    viewController.name = cellName
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    print("row\(indexPath.row)")
    print("name: \(cellName)")
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("shops")

    messageDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let text = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        let lat = snapshotValue["lat"] as! Double

        print(text)
        print(lat)

        self.myList.append(text)
        self.nearbyTableView.reloadData()
    })

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are appending every new element at the end of your data source (myList). One possible option would be to change myList so that it contains also the lat value (e.g using a tuple (String, Double), and insert every new element before the first existing element that has lat greater than its own. So, for example, if you had an existing myList like so

```
var myList: [(String, Double)] = [("Name1", 0.1), ("Name2", 0.2), ("Name4", 0.4)]
```

then you could add new element by searching the appropriate index and inserting at that index, like so

```
let myNewElement: (String, Double) = ("Name3", 0.3)

if let insertionIndex = myList.index(where: {myNewElement.1 <= $0.1}) {

    myList.insert(myNewElement, at: insertionIndex)
}

// myList = [("Name1", 0.1), ("Name2", 0.2), ("Name3", 0.3), ("Name4", 0.4)]
```

after this, the assignment in your cellForRowAt: should change, like so:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = myList[indexPath.row].0
```